# Is Citrus Framework suitable for standalone deployment

Tags: java, soap, mocking, jms, citrus-framework

I'm a developer of a BPM application. Our team has a simple hand-written tool, that allows to mock external systems over JMS and SOAP, also this tool allows us to call our own integrations.

However, we want to use something more extensible and bulletproof for integration testing purposes and Citrus Framework seems like a good alternative, but it is designed primarily to be executed like JUnit/TestNG tests, which is not suitable for the case.

We need an application that runs as a standalone one and allows simple configuration without redeployment.

Is this possible with Citrus Framework?

If not, what approach would you recommend for the purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a side project from Citrus called Citrus Simulator that is a standalone simulator for multiple message transports including JMS. The project is available on github: https://github.com/christophd/citrus-simulator

User manual (still under construction) can be found here: https://christophd.github.io/citrus-simulator/